# Adding facebook sdk in Android Studio causes 'no resource found' errors

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to upgrade to a new version of facebook sdk, and run into 200+ 'no resource found that matches xxx' errors.

I've seen many very similar questions/answers, but no helpful results.  Any pointers?

Adding the facebook library line here in the module build.gradle causes the error; removing it fixes the errors.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mazerace.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':mazeRaceAndroidCommon')
    compile project(':mazeRaceCommon')
    compile project(':mazeRaceConnection')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Top of output (partial):

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:mazeRace:generateDebugSources, :mazeRace:mockableAndroidJar, :mazeRace:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :mazeRace:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :mazeRaceAndroidCommon:generateDebugSources, :mazeRaceAndroidCommon:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :mazeRaceAndroidCommon:mockableAndroidJar, :mazeRaceAndroidCommon:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
C:\Users\Jay\Documents\projects\MazeRace\AndroidStudio\mazeRace\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
C:\Users\Jay\Documents\projects\MazeRace\AndroidStudio\mazeRace\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v17\values-v17.xml
Error:(4, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(8, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(11, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
Error:(14, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(20, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(21, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(25, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(24, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(28, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(31, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(34, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
Error:(38, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
Error:(37, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(41, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(45, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(44, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(49, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(48, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(4, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(8, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(11, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
Error:(14, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(20, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(21, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(25, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(24, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(28, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(31, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(34, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
Error:(38, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
Error:(37, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(41, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(45, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(44, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(49, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(48, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
C:\Users\Jay\Documents\projects\MazeRace\AndroidStudio\mazeRace\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(17) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(19) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(32) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(216) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(218) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(176) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(189) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(10) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(264) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification'.
Error:(276) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title'.
Error:(7) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(8) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(11) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(26) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(27) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(29) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(45) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(47) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(49, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:fontFamily'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(55) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(57) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(58) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(59) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(61) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(106, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(110, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(108, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(109, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(107, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(104, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(105, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(113, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(153, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(157, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(155, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(156, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(154, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(151, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(152, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(160, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(163, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(165) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(167) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(169) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(171) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(174) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(179) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(180) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(181) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(184) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(185) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(186) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(187) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(188) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(192) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ImageButton'.
Error:(193) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(195) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(197) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(199) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(203, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(205) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(207) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(208) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(210) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(214, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(220) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(221) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.SeekBar'.
Error:(222) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(223) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(224) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:(232, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(236, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(234, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(235, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(233, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(230, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(231, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(240) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar'.
Error:(252) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar'.
Error:(265) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Info'.
Error:(272) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Time'.
Error:(17) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(19) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(32) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(216) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(218) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(176) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(189) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(10) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(264) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification'.
Error:(276) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title'.
Error:(7) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(8) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(11) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(24) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(26) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(27) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(29) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(45) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(47) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(49, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:fontFamily'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(55) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(57) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(58) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(59) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(61) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(106, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Real issue:

```
compileSdkVersion 15
```

should be

```
compileSdkVersion 25
```

Usually you want latest compile version with latest build tools.
[Here's a nice article](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd)

---

Try this:

```
compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
}
```

Comment: Improved, but fails. 
 Care to elaborate on what this is doing?C:\Users\Jay\Documents\projects\MazeRace\AndroidStudio\mazeRace\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml with Error:(327) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar'.

Comment: Assay this `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'`

Comment: Assuming you mean to add that line, that gets me back to the original 267 errors.

Comment: This is strange. In my project it compiles without problems this way. I can suggest you to change also `compileSdkVersion` to 25.

Comment: Gah!  That was the problem all along.  I thought I had set it to 25 but must have reverted by accident.  The exclude's aren't needed at all.

Comment: Glad it helps :)